# Display Result in Data Gridview Row cell in Runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I Loaded Data From Datatable to DatagridView which look like this:

```
SerialNumber1 | Quantity | Issued Quantity | Status  |
    00001     |     1    |                 |         |
    00002     |     2    |                 |         |
```

I have this requirement which make me stuck .

I need to query The data data grid view records to verify if the loaded Serial Number is The Same as The Actual. (maybe by using linq - correct me if I'm incorrect)

Ex:

```
var dgviewData = from a in gdview1.AsEnumerable()
                 where a<string>("SerialNumber").tostring() == txtserial.text
                 select a;

if(a.Count() > 0 )
{
    // Update Status of SerialNumber 00001 to Ok 
}
else
{
   //Error Serial Not Exist on Gridview
}
```

If SerialNumbers on DGview is the same on the actual serial scanned , the status will be updated in runtime on datagridview row cell only.

Eg: DGview serial = 00001 ---> actual unit scanned = 00001

```
SerialNumber1 | Quantity | Issued Quantity | Status  |
    00001     |     1    |        1        |   Ok    |
    00002     |     2    |                 |         |
```

Thanks in Regards....

Comment: You mean write to the database, then update the DGview?

Comment: ..I just need to update the datagridview row cell only...See my Updated post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ query is a bit off, to get matching rows you should do:

```
string scannedNumber = txtserial.text;
var matchedRows = this.gdview1.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => scannedNumber.Equals(r.Cells[0].Value));
```

Then to update "Issued Quantity" (cell at index = 2) simply do:

```
foreach (var row in matchedRows)
{
    row.Cells[2].Value = 1;
}
```

Unless you want to increment that number, then use `Int32.Parse` / `.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, I think you need to add a timer to the form and on the event of the timer automatically check the database on any updations for existing data in the gridview...

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that in a certain event, you will get hold of the serial number which is scanned. So as soon as you find out the serial number, loop through the DataGrid, and check if the first column in your grid view is equal to the scanned one and if yes, update the current record.

So which part you actually stuck in? Looping through the records?